# How to use subfolder inside views with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im having this error:

```
`uninitialized constant DogsBreeds`
```

Everytime I try to access to: **animals.com/doberman**

This is my home_controller.rb:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def page1

  end

  def page2

  end
end
```

This is my routes.rb

```
 scope module: "dogs_breeds" do
  get "/doberman", to: 'home#page1'
  get "/chihuahua", to: 'home#page2'
end
```

And my views folder is organized like this:

views > home > dogs_breeds > page1.html.erb

I have tryed to create the dogs_breeds_controller.rb

```
class DogBreedsController < ApplicationController
  def page1
    
  end

  def page2

  end
end
```

But nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your routes, like this

```
scope module: "dogs_breeds" do
  get "/doberman", to: 'home#page1'
  get "/chihuahua", to: 'home#page2'
end
```

then Ruby on Rails' naming conventions expect you to have a `HomeController` controller namespaced with `DogBreeds` and placed in a `dog_breeds` subfolder like this:

```
# in app/controllers/dogs_breeds/home_controller.rb
module DogBreeds
  class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def page1
      #...
    end

    def home2
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

See [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) in the official Rails Guides.

Comment: With that solution my views hves to be like this views > dogs_breeds >  home > page1.html.erb.

Comment: Yes, correct. What would you prefer? `dog_breeds/doberman.html.erb`? Then I would just use a `DogBreedsController` and no scope at all.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Really well explained and useful